# How can I show my errors using vee-validate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have fresh Vuejs project and I came to a way to use validation so,
I use this code in template :

```
 <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                        <div class="input-group form-group" >
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text"
                                    name="email" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    placeholder="username" 
                                    v-model="form.email"
                                    v-validate="'required'">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" v-show="errors.has('email')">{{ errors.first('email') }}</div>
                            
                        </div>
 <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn">
                        </div>
</form>
```

and I import vee-validate like so :

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import  * as VeeValidate from "vee-validate";

Vue.use(VeeValidate);
```

the problem is provide me error like so :

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "errors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

My question How can I solve this error I try many platofrom to solve my problem i don't get nothing.

Comment: You should mention which version of vee-validate are you using, vee-validate v3 had a lot of changes and the above syntax isn't valid anymore.

Comment: @logaretm yes you are right, I am using vee-validate version 3, and I ware there are a lot of changes in vee-validate version 3.

I follow their migration on how to migrate to, and now everything it's okay...
thanks for your consideration